# Questions from Effective Java book(Joshua Bloch)

Tags: java

I started reading Effective Java(Joshua Bloch) and I'm currently at Chapter 3.

> Each instance of the class is inherently unique. This is true for classes that
>   represent active entities rather than values, such as **Thread**.

I don't understand which this is particularly mentioned the Thread class.

I would be glad if you can help

Comment: I think your avatar is a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

The Thread class is a prime example of a class that represents an active entities. Each thread is a "thread of execution of a program" (Oracle Docs). In other words, the Thread class models an active computation. It would not make much sense to treat a thread as a value. Two threads instantiated with the same initial state may act differently. That is why multithreading bugs, like deadlock, only sometimes occur.